# Eliminating pairs of records leaving the third one out in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table with the structure:

```
ID PRimaryKey
Name 
Balance float
SomeAmt float
```

Sample data:

```
ID  Name   Balance   SomeAmt
------------------------------
1   Kyle       5         -10
2   Kyle      -5          10
3   Kyle       5         -10
4   kyle      20          -5
```

I need to eliminate the pair of records whose sum of `Balance` and `SomeAmt` is 0 but retain the 3  and 4 records.

I was able to achieve this using cursor but it took a while to finish given the amount of data

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Desired Result:

Id   Name     Balance SomeAmt
3    Kyle     5       -10
4    Kyle     20       -5

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post as to your desired result set too because the question is not helping in understanding what you are required to do either give a better description on your requirement or provide a result set example

Comment: I would **strongly** recommend **not** to use `float` for things like money columns. `float` is inherently unsafe and prone to rounding errors. Use `Decimal(p,s)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

OK - I created a table called "test" like you have and managed to get this query to return what you want. It's a bit involved, but I think it works.

```
select * from test where id not in (
    select t1.id from test t1
    full join test t2 on t1.balance+t2.balance=0 and t1.someamt+t2.someamt=0
    where t1.id is not null and t2.id is not null and t1.id<t2.id
    and t1.id not in (
        select t2.id from test t1
        full join test t2 on t1.balance+t2.balance=0 and t1.someamt+t2.someamt=0
        where t1.id is not null and t2.id is not null and t1.id<t2.id
    )
    union
    select t2.id from test t1
    full join test t2 on t1.balance+t2.balance=0 and t1.someamt+t2.someamt=0
    where t1.id is not null and t2.id is not null and t1.id<t2.id
    and t1.id not in (
        select t2.id from test t1
        full join test t2 on t1.balance+t2.balance=0 and t1.someamt+t2.someamt=0
        where t1.id is not null and t2.id is not null and t1.id<t2.id
    )
)
```

Comment: It worked fine for the above data, but when I added more pairs of records it didn't work. The table would have several pairs of records. I tried lead and lag , but I miss the odd record out.

Comment: Really? I added extra ones in and it worked for me. Can you give me an example of it not working?

Comment: Id Name Balance SomeAmt
1 Kyle 20 -5
2 Kyle 5 -10
3 Kyle -5 10
4 Kyle 5 -10
5 Kyle -5 10
6 Kyle 5 -10
7 Kyle 15 -100
8 Kyle -15 100
9 Kyle 15 -100                              The result set should be                                                                   Id Name Balance SomeAmt
1 Kyle 20 -5
4 Kyle 5 -10
9 Kyle 15         -100                              but I got...                                                               Id Name Balance SomeAmt
1 Kyle 20 -5
4 Kyle 5 -10
6 Kyle 5 -10
9 Kyle 15 -100  Thanks.